# Fatal error when fetch data from my CoreData and presented it in a Table View using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, fatal-error

I've been trying to find a way to fetch data from my CoreData and present it in a cell in my TableView. The Cell has a title and a subtitle, in which the title will have the subject of the content and the subtitle will have the date. I've tried a couple different ways, the path I took doesn't give me any syntax errors, but I get a debug error.

```
public class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    public var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
        let dataFetchedRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Data")
        let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "Data.subject", ascending: true)
        dataFetchedRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor]

        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: dataFetchedRequest,
            managedObjectContext: self.context,
            sectionNameKeyPath: "Data.subject",
            cacheName: nil)

        frc.delegate = self

        return frc

        }()

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if (fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) == false) {
            print("An error occurred: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    public func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
            return sections.count
        }

        return 0
    }
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
            let currentSection = sections[section] as! NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
            return currentSection.numberOfObjects
        }

        return 0
    }

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let data = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Data

        cell.textLabel?.text = data.subject
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data.date

        return cell
    }
}

let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: dataFetchedRequest,
        **managedObjectContext: self.context,** <-- This line gives me error
        sectionNameKeyPath: "Data.subject",
        cacheName: nil)
```

> error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a property:

```
public var context: NSManagedObjectContext!
```

You are never setting it to an NSManagedObjectContext, so it is nil. That is the nil you are fatally and unexpectedly finding.

Comment: Thanks, I shall do that.

Comment: But do you mind explaining how exactly to do that? I am very new to swift and coding in general, I'm trying to learn as I experiment.

Comment: How on earth do I know? I can't see your project. I have no idea how you created and reached this view controller to begin with. But it was your responsibility to initialize its instance variables before using them.

Comment: By the way, if you are truly "new to swift and coding", then I would have to say that choosing to use Core Data was a really bad decision. Core Data is absolutely _not_ a beginner technology.

Comment: I used a SQLite database at first, and it worked fine. And I heard about Core Data and I wanted to try it out. But yeah, I'll initialize it. That's what i really wanted to know, I didn't know what you mean by "setting".

Comment: If you don't know what it means to set a variable, you really _are_ a beginner. May I suggest you stop and read my book? Start right at the beginning: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html

Comment: I have somewhat of a general idea now, but I'll read your book, seems very helpful. Thanks.